Problems displaying back to top button
I am encountering a display problem for this button which appears when loading the page even without having scrolled on it.
Secondly I can't change the shape of the arrow inside for a more standard and thick version.
Knowing that this code must remain on a single page as presented given that it is an integration into a no code site
How to solve these two problems ?
<script> document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault()); </script>
<script> document.onselectstart = () => { event.preventDefault(); } </script><style>
 .BTT-button {
 z-index: 20;
 display: flex;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 1.5vw;
 right: 2rem;
 width: 3rem;
 height: 3rem;
 background: white;
 transition: 0.5s;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border-radius: 21px;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 box-shadow: 1px -2px 6px #766E6E;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
 html {
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }
</style>
<script>
 const topButton = document.createElement('div');
 topButton.innerHTML = '<button onclick="topFunction()" class="BTT-button" title="Go to top"> < </button>'
 document.body.append(topButton);
 let mybutton = document.querySelector(".BTT-button");
 window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };
 function scrollFunction() {
 if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
 mybutton.style.opacity = "1";
 } else {
 mybutton.style.opacity = "0";
 }
 }
 function topFunction() {
 document.body.scrollTop = 0;
 document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
 }
 if (document.querySelector('.whats-app-bubble')) {
 mybutton.style.bottom = '6rem';
 }
 </script><style> .whats-app-bubble { right: 100px !important; width: 64px !important; } </style>


for info and the fun : a toplink that shows only once content is tall enough and without javascript : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QWRrqmb (grid,floatting pseudo,position:sticky and containerquerie used)

you need to set the initial opacity to 0
for the arrow I suggest to use svg, in the code I have used html up arrow


document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
 document.onselectstart = () => { event.preventDefault(); } 
 
 const topButton = document.createElement('div');
 topButton.innerHTML = '<button onclick="topFunction()" class="BTT-button" title="Go to top"> &#8679; </button>'
 document.body.append(topButton);
 let mybutton = document.querySelector(".BTT-button");
 window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };
 function scrollFunction() {
 if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
 mybutton.style.opacity = "1";
 } else {
 mybutton.style.opacity = "0";
 }
 }
 function topFunction() {
 document.body.scrollTop = 0;
 document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
 }
 if (document.querySelector('.whats-app-bubble')) {
 mybutton.style.bottom = '6rem';
 }
.BTT-button {
 z-index: 20;
 display: flex;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 1.5vw;
 right: 2rem;
 width: 3rem;
 height: 3rem;
 background: white;
 transition: 0.5s;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border-radius: 21px;
 box-shadow: 1px -2px 6px #766E6E;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0;
 }
 html {
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }
.whats-app-bubble { right: 100px !important; width: 64px !important; }
<div> 
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
<h1>some text</h1>
 

</div>



